# Pandas - drop level in pivot table, keeping index as column name

Tags: pandas

I have this `df_pivot` with more than one level:

```
       team    sum                          
                 F     FD     FF    FT     G
9     team1  365.0  145.0  206.0  14.0  60.0
10    team2  274.0   96.0  171.0   7.0  50.0
15    team3  294.0   92.0  191.0  11.0  42.0
```

How do I change it into:

```
      team       F     FD     FF    FT     G
9     team1  365.0  145.0  206.0  14.0  60.0
10    team2  274.0   96.0  171.0   7.0  50.0
15    team3  294.0   92.0  191.0  11.0  42.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fix with

```
df = df.set_index('team')['sum'].reset_index()
```